# react native navigate with different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

As a newbie in react-native i'm trying find a way to use `react-navigation` with different files without a navbar to navigate (for example just click on a button in the login view to enter the main view, clicking on log out button return to login view).

With react-navigation i made a global component 'Nav' and i placed in the main AppRegistry call:

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Nav);`

While in the Navigator.js:

```
export const Nav = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginView },
  AddStream: { screen: AddStreamView },
});
```

When i run 
`react-native run-android`
i get the first view loaded under a white space (it should be the navigator, that i don't want in my app)

Now how can i remove the Nav from the view and how can i change View onPress a button component in another file?

There is another package that fill better my desire?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig), setting the the `headerMode` to `none` should do the trick. This will hide the header on all of the screens defined in that StackNavigator. Example:

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: LoginView },
    AddStream: { screen: AddStreamView },
},{
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

If you want to control the visibility of the header so that it appears on some of the screens but not all of them, then you can set `headerMode` to `screen` and for each individual screen set [the navigation prop for `header: { visible: false }`. [See docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Screen-Navigation-Options). For example, if you are creating the screen component in another file, it might look like this:

```
// In the main file:
const Nav = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: LoginView },
    AddStream: { screen: AddStreamView },
},{
    headerMode: 'screen',
});

// Hidden for your Login screen:
export default class LoginView extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: { visible: false }
    }
    // etc...
}

// Visible for your AddStream screen:
export default class AddStreamView extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: { visible: true }
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Edit: missed the second part of your question.
For navigating to a different screen, you really should go through [the Hello World tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) as it explains it. Specifically, [this section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/#Adding-a-New-Screen). Relevant example code from the tutorial:

```
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
            <Button
             onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
             title="Chat with Lucy"
            />
       </View>
    );
}
```

In your case, `'Chat'` would be either `'Login'` or `'AddStream'`.